# How to configure Atom to autocomplete Django templates

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I need to find a way/package to make Atom use autocomplete for Django projects, especially Django templates.
I found this [package](https://atom.io/packages/django-templates) in Atom's installer, but it doesn't include a shortcut for auto completion of this syntax {%  %}, {{  }} which I need the most.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You could make your own snippets in Atom.

To do that go to **Edit > Snippets**

In the document that open's you can paste this bit:

```
'.html.django':
  'Example snippet':
    'prefix': '%%'
    'body': '{% $1 %}$2'
```

This example would expand to `{% %}`, placing your cursor inside. To trigger it you type `%%` and hit `tab`. A second `tab` would place the cursor after the closing bracket.

The `.html.django` part means this snippet is active only in documents that are marked as `HTML (Django)`

I don't see why you would need a snippet for `{{ }}` as Atom auto-close's the brackets.

For more information read this - http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable atom-django package
2. I installed the django-templates package
3. in the django-templates settings in the option *Default to Django Templates For File Paths Containing*  add the value  *directory_name*/
4. reload atom
5. When you create an html file inside templates folder the it recognizes it as html django template

I configured it and it works

Comment: For me, point 3 was the key :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation and bit explored more inline with @4140tm's comment and found [atom-django-templates](https://github.com/benjohnson/atom-django-templates) repo. One can follow the steps given in the repo to have autocomplete in Atom editor 
OR please follow below steps that I followed on my Mac.

**How to Do it**
 1. Open "/Users/YourAccountName/.atom/snippets.cson"
 2. Copy content from [django-templates.cson](https://github.com/benjohnson/atom-django-templates/blob/master/snippets/django-templates.cson)
 3. Paste it in "/Users/YourAccountName/.atom/snippets.cson"
 4. Open any .html file and hurrah.... You are ready to Rock.

**How it looks**
[image: snippets.cson]
[image: Sample Autocomplete In HTML 1]
[image: Sample Autocomplete In HTML 2]

Comment: it works if you change '.text.html.django' to '.html' in the first line